# How to fix 'Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant:'

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to run a selected build variant but giving me following error in Run tab,

> Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: madhyapradesh-debug

So kindly suggest the solution to it.

Comment: I wonder why every Android Studio update is so painful. I prefer to keep existing version as long as possible because of this.

Answer (score 357):

First clean your project by

```
Build -> Clean project
```

Then rebuild project

```
Build -> Rebuild project
```

Then run your project.
I hope this will work.

if not then go to

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart
```

The last option is you can sync Gradle again in case nothing worked

Comment: File > Invalidate Cashes / Restart... helped.

Comment: It is sad that such problems keep happening now and then.

Comment: File->Invalidate Cashes /restart-> Invalidate and restart
 worked

Comment: I have done this before and it has helped, but this time it hasn't. I had to do the gradle sync.

Comment: File->Invalidate Cashes /restart-> Invalidate and restart worked well when I check very old commit in git to test

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart worked for me :)

Comment: File > Sync project with Gradle Files worked for me :)

Answer (score 146):

Your Gradle is out of sync. Go to: `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`. It should fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Pressing shift twice, searching ```sync gradle``` then pressing enter do the same stuff if you are lazy to move the cursor by mouse or touchpad.

Answer (score 83):

**This is because your gradle version in project build.gradle configuration is too old for a newer Android Studio version**, like Android Studio 3.6.1,

**1.** you should change the gradle configuration into a newer one under:
*build.gradle(project)->buildscript->dependencies->classpath;*

for example, you should change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

into:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

**2.** after this, may be you should also change the configuration in *gradle-wrapper.properties* into a newer version, for example, change:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

into:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**3.** after this, may be you should also add `google()` at:

*build.gradle(project)->buildscript->repositories*

and

*build.gradle(project)->allprojects->repositories*

Comment: Update the classpath in the Project build  works for me.Thank you!

Comment: After updating my gradle versions, I had to also `Sync Project with Gradle Files` to have it work. Thanks!!

Comment: But shouldn't be this applicable to all the projects. I find this strange incase of 2 project with same Gradle and build tool plugin projects for 1 it is working fine and for other suddenly started throwing error for last 2 weeks, before that it was working fine.

Comment: They talk about 'gradle version' and 'plugin version'? Is distri-url->plugin and classpath->gradle? Or vice verca? See link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin I want to know the latest versions.

Answer (score 30):

I faced this problem today.

Select nothing from the installation option and click on the add icon button. Select Run Gradle task.
[image]

Double click on the run Gradle task and there will be a pop-up option like the image. Change the first option to the app and the second option to install debug like the image.

Now finally you solved the problem

[image]

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: on windows Run tab->Edit config further as was said above then that plus mark appers on scroll. Also had picked up launch activity name in Launch option in advance.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Suberp....This should be high voted answer

Comment: wow, it worked! but how can you explain

Answer (score 27):

I have the same issue with a Cordova Project after I updated Android Studio to 3.6.1

As a workaround (at least for the first installation of the app) I use installDebug Gradle Task from Gradle Tab View -> Tasks -> Install

[image]

Comment: this fix the problem I had with my LibGdx game. Thx!

Comment: My computer's power was disconnected due to an electricity issue while I was working on an android project. So I started facing this issue after that. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

For me doing:

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

worked fine ^^

Answer (score 9):

For me the solution was apparently to update the Gradle plugin...

Comment: to which version

Answer (score 9):

### Workaround 1

Create a new configuration for Run with the same parameters as the default config app. This work for me.

1. Run
2. Edit Configuration
3. Add New Configuration (NOT COPY) -> Android App
4. Rename
5. Choose app Module
6. Apply

---

### Workaround 2

1. Use the task for install in `Gradle Tab View -> Tasks -> Install`
2. `Run` the app.

---

### Workaround 3

1. Delete .gradle folder
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart ...
3. `Run` the app

Comment: Workaround 1 worked by deleting the app run config and resyncing the Gradle.

Comment: workaround 1 worked but plz can u tell me the reason behind that?? why does it works? and why it wasn't working before?

Answer (score 7):

I faced this problem today.

Select "Default APK" from the installation option and click on the add icon button. Select "Gradle-aware Make"->"OK"
[image]

Comment: Nothing else worked but this did.

Answer (score 5):

Do follow the three steps:

1. **Clean project**: Build(menu) >> Clean Project
2. **Sync project**: File(Menu) >> Sync Project with Gradle Files
3. **Rebuild project**: Build(menu) >> Rebuild Project

Now run your app and enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a gradle sync and run will do the job. I was facing this after gradle plugin update too. Gradle sync might not have happened sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

First **clean** your project and then **rebuild the project** it will solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Set Deploy to NOTHING worked for me. (kudos to above nvatvm above)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this will just run the application, but without updating it. At least if it's not an instant app.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project`. If it doesn't work then the **Easy**, **Hardcore**, **Fast** approach which works for me was just deleting the two following folder named `.gradle` and `.idea` after closing the IDE and restart it -

[image]

Comment: Only removing .gradle folder actually helped me. Invalidate Caches / Restart, Rebuilding project had no effect

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are not working for me.
The only solution that worked for me was to delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folders.

Comment: I tried all the soludion mentioned in below answers and comments. Neither those workaround or your mentioned work around is working for me :(. Also I noticed a strange a problem for another project with same Gradle and Android Gradle plugin version it is working fine. The project for which I got issue was working fine even after Android Studio update to Dolphin but suddenly past 2 week this issue occured.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your  have set `applicationId "com.example.myapp"` in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

And from **app** -> **Edit Configurations**, ensure that you have selected "**Default Activity**"

Answer (score 2):

Project Structure -
Suggestions -
Update Gradle

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following command on the Android Studio Terminal:

- `gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

Comment: Thanks, dear, you are a lifesaver. Very Helpful in my case

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to upgrade Android Studio from "Artic Fox | 2021.3.1 Canary 12" to "Artic Fox | 2021.3.1 Canary 13"

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the **Gradle** version:
go to **File** -> **Project structure**, then update the Android Gradle Plugin version, and Gradle Version to the latest stable versions(now **7.0.2** & **7.2** respectively)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

View Gradle Table => right click the application => click "Reload Gradle Project"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have **Build Variant** selected:
Go to **Menu > Build > Select Build Variant**

Select a build variant that ends with **Debug** for the Release Variants you need the signing certificate configured correctly.

Comment: My build variant is greyed out but my device is plugged in and recognized by Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

setting Installation Options-> Deploy: `APK from app bundle`  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me like the clean build, rebuild and invalidate cache restart.
Here's my solution to this problem.

The workaround was to delete the existing app configuration from Run/Debug Configurations.
[image]

After that add new configuration by clicking the left top + icon and then add Android App.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After migrate my project to another computer I get the same error.

The Solution for my case was:

The problem was because I had diferent Java Versions in the .gradle and the Settings Build Tools. After I update both I made a Rebuild Project and my project compile again.  Here are my correct configurations:

[image]

My build.gradle.kts
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @applixy worked for me.
1.Just note to update the classpath to the latest version
in project->build.gradle to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

2.And in the gradle->wrapper.proprties just apply sync with gradle upon
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

3.My project already had the google() method on allprojects{}.
So build your project and run you are good to go.

Answer (score -3):

Error:
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug

Solution :
Go to:

1. File
2. project structure  (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S)
3. Suggestions
4. Update Graddle

Then wait for downloading griddle to solve your problem.

Comment: These questions has already similar answers. Please don't copy other's answers.