# Android studio 3.6 issue : ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.6

Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug

when update to android studio 3.6 version, this issue come out, but 3.5 is ok at the same project.

And I can find the apk in the outputs/apk folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant:'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with a Cordova Project after I updated Android Studio to 3.6.1

As a workaround (at least for the first installation of the app) I use installDebug Gradle Task from Gradle Tab View -> Tasks -> Install

[image]

I also have issues with Build -> Build Apks so I use assembleRelease Gradle Task from Tasks -> build