# "Operation Succeeded" in Android Studio 4.1, with no action

Tags: android, android-studio

Have anyone faced this issue with the new Android Studio 4.1. When I run the app to the simulator, everything works and builds. Later it also shows a message

[image]

In the run, the error message is

```
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Error loading build artifacts from: LOCATION/build/outputs/apk/act/debug/output-metadata.json
```

Comment: happens to me too

Comment: I solved the issue by upgrading the gradle

Comment: 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' worked with me on gradle version 4.1.0

Comment: Invalidate caches/Restart is the solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just figured out that, if you upgrade your gradle in one branch and change your branch to something which had the old gradle, you may face this issue.

I just updated the gradle and it fixed the issue.For me I change from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
```

Comment: this does not help

Comment: currently, its 4.1.1

Comment: sure, i mean it still pops up and stays forever, even on most recent plugin versions

Comment: basically my problem was that the app was not really pushed to the emulator.

Comment: This does not work. any solution for 4.1.1 version?

Comment: It doesn't help me at all. Any solutions guys? I have updated to 4.1.1 but same issue both with Emulator and Physical device.

Comment: I have com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 and it´s not working

Comment: @JohnDeer try another version of android studio

Answer (score 51):

I see this when switching branches from one that uses Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1 and Gradle 6.1.1 to one that uses Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.1 and Gradle 6.5.

The workaround here is to manually run File > Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working like charm after sync project with Gradle files.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I  tried all the work around provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr  .... For me none of the solutions worked. I am still looking for solution. Also I have mentioned in one of the answer the strange behaviour observed with respect to issue.

Answer (score 7):

Changing o updating your gradle version is not the real solution.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.?.?'
```

if you change the value this is provoking a new project sync with the files of your project.

so **the real solution is to synchronize the project with the Gradle files**:

`File` > `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed my issue. Go to

> Run > Edit Configurations > Android App > app

On General tab change Launch option to

> Default Activity

In my case it was selected

> Nothing

Answer (score 3):

I met with this issue when I manually copied some files of one project into another(they were related to gradle).

So, In my case, the main issue was with the settings.gradle file. There is this line in the file:

```
rootProject.name = "Your App Name"
```

Make sure it is exactly similar to the home folder of your project.

Comment: Exactly, when I cloned the project onto another computer, I created a new folder name, and as you said, when I changed it to match the folder name, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of Gradle 4.1.1, Will work properly in Gradle 4.1.0,
Please use :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

First **Build->clean** your project and then **Build->Rebuild Project** it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

A possibility why This problem happens because of the run configuration. go to run configurations, within Before launch add **Gradle-aware Make**. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

File/Invalidate Caches/Restart worked for me.
Note: I already applied above mentioned solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using RedMi android device, seems all the MI android phone should has this issue.

I tried all but doesn't work. The solution is turn off
`Turn on MIUI optimization` in `Developer options`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurred to me on beta version of the android studio. I fixed it by upgrading it to the **latest version** and upgrade the gradle to the next **highest version**.

This problem occurred to me when I tried to run jetpack compose samples from github.