# How to resolve this error?! Having trouble in android studio

Tags: java, android

Using Android Studio, version 4.1.0.
the following error comes: -

01/27 14:53:12: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
**Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: ERROR: APK path is not specified for module "Easy Video Downloader"**

Comment: Check if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr