# Android Studio Canary - 020.3.1 Canary 9, Not launching application

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I click my menu-> Run -> Run 'app'

It's Gradle Build Running.

I got a message like 'Launch Succeeded' but nothing installed on my mobile

```
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Error loading build artifacts from: C:\Users\name\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json
```

Comment: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: `Build -> Clean project`  `Build -> Rebuild project` and then `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr/64373002

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I tried 'Invalidate and restart' too

Comment: Hi @Livin Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AxesGrinds yes I found

Answer (score 0):

[image]

SOLUTION : Just rebuild the nothing else

Comment: For me none of the wok around provided here worked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr  ....  I am still looking for solution.