# How can i fix that 'Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Couldn't get post build model.'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I get this error when i trying run app on my virtual device.
I tried deploy "Nothing" but it didnt help.
I tried change gradle version on newest, but didint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hope you have tried all the work around provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440572/how-to-fix-unable-to-determine-application-id-com-android-tools-idea-run-apkpr  .... For me none of the solutions worked. I am still looking for solution.